# interrupt vs disrupt

Tags: difference

what is the difference between **interrupt** and **disrupt**?
I searched in google :
**interrupt** :(v) stop the continuous progress of (an activity or process).
**disrupt** : (v)interrupt (an event, activity, or process) by causing a disturbance or problem.

Could you please provide some examples to understand more easily?

Comment: "The meeting was briefly interrupted when Mr Jones wished to ask a question of the chairman." "The meeting was disrupted when protesters invaded the meeting room."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the comment left by @Tetsujin illustrates the example pretty well. We are more likely to use *disrupt* when there is a lot of commotion involved in the disturbance.

For example:

- A child can *interrupt* a discussion by asking a question; a child can *disrupt* a conversation by throwing a tantrum.
- A poker game can be *interrupted* when the phone rings, and *disrupted* when an angry player overturns the card table.
- Bus service could be *interrupted* if a bus breaks down; it might be *disrupted* if all of the bus drivers go on strike.
- A passing rainstorm can *interrupt* a baseball game; an [earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_World_Series#The_Loma_Prieta_earthquake) can *disrupt* the World Series.